# How to retrieve title from dyamically formed web pages

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, spynner

I'm working on a bookmarking app using Django and would like to extract the title from web pages that use javascript to generate the title. I've looked at windmill and installed/ran selenium, which worked, but I believe these tools are more than what I need to obtain the title of a web page. I'm currently trying to use spynner, but haven't been successful in retrieving the contents after the page is fully rendered. Here is the code that I currently have...

```
from spynner import Browser
from pyquery import PyQuery
browser = Browser()
browser.set_html_parser(PyQuery)
browser.load("https://www.coursera.org/course/techcity")
```

I receive a SpynnerTimeout: Timeout reached: 10 seconds error when executing the last line in a python shell. If I execute the last statement again, it will return True, but only the page before the javascript is run is returned, which doesn't have the "correct" page title. I also tried the following:

```
browser.load("https://www.coursera.org/course/techcity", wait_callback=wait_load(10))
browser.soup("title")[0].text
```

But this also returns the incorrect title - 'Coursera.org' (i.e. title before the javascript is run).

Here are my questions:

1. Is there a more efficient recommended approach for extracting a web page title that is dynamically generated with javascript, that uses some other python tool/library? If so, what is that recommended approach? - any example code appreciated.
2. If using spynner is a good approach, what should I be doing to get the title after the page is loaded, or even better, right after the title has been rendered by the javascript. The code I have now is just what I pieced together from a blog post and looking at the source for spynner on github.

Comment: You're going to want a library that can interpret and execute Javascript. These are often called "headless browsers." Selenium is one. However, I believe Spynner actually has support for this. Take a look at the code example on http://code.google.com/p/spynner/ and Google around for ways to wait for a page to finish loading and then how to access DOM attributes. If you add a call to `browser.wait_page_load()` before trying to read the title, it might start magically working.

Comment: wait_page_load() doesn't seem to exist in the current version of spynner, but I did try wait_load(10) and it returns the Timeout error.